# jQuery Templates data display problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been struggling to get jQuery.tmpl() to populate a JSP page using a JSON file I am creating through JSTL.

JSON (/misc/managed_solutions/results.htm):

```
    var dataTable = [

            {
                firmName: "name",
                portfolioName: "Fund Allocation Portfolio",
                firmAum: "3.2394E8",
                portfolioAum: "2.3659865E7",
                objTypeDesc: "Capital Preservation/Current Income",
                gipsFlg: "Yes",
                inceptionDt: "01/01/2000",
                stateProvCd: "CA",
                pdfFileNm: "TremendousGrowth.pdf",
                agencyNm1: "name",
                agencyNm2: "name",
                agencyNm3: "name",
                agencyNm4: "name"
            }
            ,
            {
                firmName: "name",
                portfolioName: "Capital Allocation Portfolio",
                firmAum: "4.2394E8",
                portfolioAum: "4.3659865E7",
                objTypeDesc: "Capital Appreciation - Aggressive",
                gipsFlg: "Yes",
                inceptionDt: "01/01/2005",
                stateProvCd: "CA",
                pdfFileNm: "CapitalAllocation.pdf",
                agencyNm1: "name",
                agencyNm2: "name",
                agencyNm3: "name",
                agencyNm4: "name"
            }
            ,
            {
                firmName: "name",
                portfolioName: "name",
                firmAum: "2.2394E8",
                portfolioAum: "1.3659865E7",
                objTypeDesc: "Capital Appreciation - Moderate",
                gipsFlg: "No",
                inceptionDt: "01/01/2008",
                stateProvCd: "TX",
                pdfFileNm: "Global Core Equity.pdf",
                agencyNm1: "name",
                agencyNm2: "name",
                agencyNm3: "name",
                agencyNm4: "name"
            }

];
```

jQuery JS

```
function getPortfolioData( start ) {

    var markup = "<tr>" +
                    "<td><p>${firmName}</p>" +
                        "<a href='/path/to/content/${pdfFileNm}'>${portfolioName}</a>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td>" +
                        "<p>${firmAum}</p>" +
                        "<p>${portfolioAum}</p>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td>" +
                        "<p>${objTypeDesc}</p>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td>" +
                        "<p>${gipsFlg}</p>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td>" +
                        "<p>${inceptionDt}</p>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td>" +
                        "<p>${agencyNm1}</p>" +
                        "<p>${agencyNm2}</p>" +
                        "<p>${agencyNm3}</p>" +
                        "<p>${agencyNm4}</p>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td>" +
                        "<p>${stateProvCd}</p>" +
                    "</td>" +
                 "</tr>";

    $.template( "portfoliosTemplate", markup );

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: '/misc/managed_solutions/results.htm?startPosition=' + start + '&viewRows=3',
        jsonp: "$callback",
        success: showPortfolio()
    });

    function showPortfolio(dataTable) {

        // Remove current set of portfolio items
        $( ".data-table.tpm tbody" ).empty();

        // Render the template items for each portfolio
        $.tmpl( "portfoliosTemplate", dataTable ).appendTo( ".data-table.tpm tbody" );
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="data-table tpm">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

RESULT

```
<table class="data-table tpm">  
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p></p>
                <a href="/path/to/content/"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've managed to get the html markup to display within tbody, but none of the values.  Furthermore, the markup only displays once, telling me that no iteration is occurring.

Any ideas?

DKM

Answer (score 1):

Given your markup, data, and JavaScript, your code works fine:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Xdw2v/

I have a hunch that the problem you're seeing is from your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: '/misc/managed_solutions/results.htm?startPosition=' + start + '&viewRows=3',
    jsonp: "$callback",
    success: showPortfolio()
});
```

Specifically, the `success` property is set to *the results of executing the `showPortfolio()` method*. This is causing your template to get rendered immediately (with no data). I think you really want:

```
success: showPortfolio
```

That  is, a reference to your `showPortfolio` method instead of the results of executing it.

Comment: I see that what you did does work on jsfiddle, but it uses the json as a local variable rather than as an external file which isn't what I need.  I also noticed that when I removed the '()' from the showPortfolio method I actually get nothing in my tbody - no markup, even.

Comment: @dylanmac: Judging by your question I assumed you thought the problem was with the `.tmpl()` call. To eliminate this possibility, I moved the data into a local variable. Your templating code works fine, therefore there *must* be a problem with your AJAX call. Have you looked in FireBug to make sure the data you expect is coming back? Do any errors occur on the page? Does your success callback ever get called?

Comment: Yeah I think you're right.  The data is retrieved but the success function is not being called.  I added console.log to it and nothing outputs.  What the hell (and yes I removed the '()')?

Comment: Are you sure the request needs JSONP? JSONP is usually used for cross-domain requests. If your request is to a local URL you should be okay without it. (Just change `datatype` to `json` and remove the `jsonp` parameter)

Comment: Still no change.  The function just isn't being called.

Comment: In the console tab in Firebug, what comes back? Are you seeing the data you expect, or is there an error message?

Comment: Well a friend and I eventually figured it out over the weekend.  I simply had to remove the "var dataTable =" from the JSON.  That's it.  An interesting note is that I could not use the technique where you put the markup in an ID'd script block in the parent page.  It would iterate over the markup as per the number of records in the JSON object, but it would not populate the JSON data into the markup itself.